# Set theory: creating a set of number pairs from a set of numbers, how to correctly define the set of number pairs?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $p$ be a prime number and let $A = \{k : k\in\Bbb Z^+, 1\le k\le p\}$. 
I want to create a set called $B$ that contains every $(k,k+2)$ number pair.

For example if $p=5$, then $A = \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and $B=\{(1,3),(2,4),(3,5),(4,6),(5,7)\}$.

Is $B = \{(k, k+2), k\in A\}$ mathematically correct, does it contain every number pair, or if not, how should I formulate it?

Comment: **Emphatically yes**. There's nothing wrong with the way you've written it. Some people sometimes separate the $(k, k+2)$ and the $k \in A$ by a vertical bar $|$ rather than a comma, but that has nothing to do with the correctness. It is perfectly clear.

Comment: I agree.  What you have written is entirely clear, and that's the important thing.

Comment: Thanks for u both!